# multi store language Change currency on a page

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a deal.phtml file which loads about 20pcs of products on a specific page. I have a multi store language shop now and I have noticed that the price is not switching when choosing another currency.

Just stuck with the local currency and symbol (the currency switching is working for all other pages just this page with the deal.phtlm file). This is the first code lines from start:

`<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position', 'desc')->addAttributeToSelect('*')) && $_collectionSize = $_products->getSize()): ?>
 <?php $symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_code)->getSymbol();?>`

Any idea how to include other currencies? I want to include USD, EURO, GBP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing:

```
$storeID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

$symbol = Mage::app()->getStore($storeID)->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
```

Comment: I have updated my questions. Where and how should I include the code? I have tried in a number of ways, but I always get a white/empty page as result.